# Input for block breaker game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The movement within my block breaker game seems to be a bit jittery and I'm not entirely sure why.

Any help would be super appreciated.

```cs
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public float speed = 10f;
public float movement;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime * movement));
}
```

Comment: @3Dave the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) explicitly recommend to not do that: `For reading the delta time it is recommended to use Time.deltaTime instead because it automatically returns the right delta time if you are inside a FixedUpdate function or Update function.)`

Comment: Do you need your thing (no idea of the name in english) to be controlled using physics ? For a block breaker game I really can't see the point of having this as a rigidbody. You want physic on the ball instead probably

Comment: @Jichael Sorry I'm kind of new to scripting. I can't see any other way to move the paddle other than using Translate, but that isn't used for detecting collisions I believe? 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixM2W2tPn6c

Comment: But does your paddle need to handle/detect collision ? Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see how that would help the gameplay. On a block breaker game, the only object I'd make it deal with actual physic is the ball, but that's just a first guess

Comment: @Jichael I would guess this code is for the bord on the lower screen the user moves in order to not drop the ball so Collision detection would be essential here ;) The paddle itself does not necessarily have to do the detection itself but if you don't use the Rigidbody for moving it no other Rigidbody (ball) can detect the collisions either!

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking ^ but wasn’t sure if I was right or not haha. 

Also @derHugo I was wondering if my approach is right with having input in update and movement within fixed update?

Comment: @derHugo What ? of course it can.  You only need one rigidbody to have collision detection. Rigidbody collides with every collider, that's the point of it. And that's why I won't ever use physic movement for the paddle, and it won't be as smooth and unnecessary calculations

Comment: @Jichael nope. Checkout the [Collision action matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) (at the bottom). What you mean are maybe static colliders which works if the object is not moved .. but if they move they always should be Rigidbody (e.g. kinematic) because your objects might just pass through each other without detecting the collision otherwise if they move

Comment: @derHugo, yeah my bad. I meant static colliders. And for everything that move kinematic rigidbodies (but using transform, not rigidbody Move/etc)

Comment: @Jichael as soon as it is a Rigidbody, also a kinematic one, you should never use the `transform` anymore, only the rigidbody methods. Otherwise you break the physics

Comment: On the link you posted, it says that Kinematic rigidbody can be moved by the transform (and I've always done that). But for regular rb, yes of course

Answer (score 3):

Within `FixedUpdate` the `transform` values might differ from the ones of the `Rigidbody` values computed by Physics.

You should rather only use and update the `Rigidbody` component in `FixedUpdate`:

```
//               |
//               V
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime * movement);
```

Comment: Ah I see @derHugo being new to scripting I didn't know rb.position was a thing. Thanks I'll give this a go! :)